# Who and when was this Action Man villain in constant pain?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

There was a cartoon, *probably* *Action Man*, several years ago with a central villain (not Dr X) who felt constant pain (but didn't behave like it). He could share/fire/distribute his pain via some kind of black and white lava-lamp-esque energy.

I remember he was a very strange villain because in one episode he was going to 'distribute' his pain via a satellite dish but he was far more happy and relieved than malevolent. Then the heroes blew it up in a standard good vs evil way, forcing him to take back the full burden.

Does anyone know what episode, cartoon and villain I'm remembering?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is **Alexander Paine**, the main antagonist in the TV show *A.T.O.M. (AKA Action Man: Alpha Teens on Machines)*, specifically the episode [*House of Paine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_A.T.O.M._episodes).

His shtick is that he's in constant pain. With the assistance of some goons and patsies, he devises a machine that will share his pain with the entire city using sound waves. It's got bubbling tubes like a lava-lamp.

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Yes spot-on. The black+white lava-lamp bit in this episode is in his eyes when he gets it back, and the ball of energy on top of the dish (a kind of cross between "rorschach's mask"  and lava-lamp) which our heroes cunningly solve by reversing the polarity of the energy.

Fortunately for a kid's cartoon the villain stated several times he could fire his pain into the mountains and walk away but he wants to inflict it on others for no reason.